# Importing external libraries in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java application programming. wondering how to import package? I am using Eclipse.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import se.kontoret.testapi.*;  //this is required.
```

Is it same like dll file in .net where one must have .dll files and add as reference?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Downloaded the external library which is of .jar extension and Configure it using build path for a normal java project
2. You can create a Maven project and add the dependencies there so that Maven will download it to your .m2 repo and you can import it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is similar.

To do this, right click on your project, navigate to Build Path -> Add external archives, and then select the .jar file which contains your external dependency.